# How can I get the Console.ReadKey() keywork to work in AppHarbor?

Tags: c#, appharbor

I am hosting a C# application which needs to have the Console.ReadKey() statement to work properly. AppHarbor doesnt seem to support this and it terminates my applicaiton with the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.]
mscorlib_ni!System.Console.ReadKey(Boolean)+0x1ec
ZiFM!ZiFM.Program.Main(System.String[])+0xc0
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but appharbor does not support console apps and probably that is why you are having problems...

Comment: BTW, is your app a console app?

Comment: @Ademar Note that AppHarbor has support for beackground workers: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/background-workers

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make sense to read from the console on AppHarbor; your console apps run non-interactively and are intended for background processes.

Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do? If you're wanting to read keys via a users browser, you'd need to build a website and deploy that, which is *very* different to writing a console application.

Comment: In my case i am using the Console.ReadLine() to not terminate the application. Then i use System.Timers.Timer to do some work each x minutes. But when it executes the Console.Readline() it throws this error "The handle is invalid." Always

Comment: Why not just do the work in a loop in the main thread with a Thread.Sleep or something?

while (true) { DoStuff(); Thread.Sleep(1000000); }